# Django: Checking if submodel of submodel is null?

Tags: python, sql, django

Suppose I have three models, a `County` model who has many `Communities`. Each `Community` has many `Mall` models.

I know if I wanted to check if a County had any communities, I would simply do `County.objects.filter(community__isnull=False).distinct()`, but is there a way I can:

1. Get all the counties that have one or more malls?
2. Suppose each more has an IntegerField with the number of stores. How would I get the counties with malls with more than `x` stores?

Comment: You might want to check out [django-prefetcher](https://github.com/ionelmc/django-prefetch)

Comment: `County.objects.filter(community__isnull=False, community__malls__stores__gte=1).distinct()` where `stores` is an integer field with number of stores. (is that what you want?)